# Using JQuery to dynamically change Selected item in SELECT

Tags: jquery, json

Thanks to the helpful users of Stackoverflow, I'm getting there slowly with JQuery, but I have come across a new problem that I can't seem to find a solution to.

I have the following JQuery function:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip();
    $("#eventLocation").on("change", function (e) {
        $.getJSON("/common/ajaxCalls.php?task=locationEdit&eventLocation=" + $("#eventLocation").val(),

        function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                if (item.field == "name") {
                    $("#name").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "address") {
                    $("#address").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "postcode") {
                    $("#postcode").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "directions") {
                    $("#directions").val(item.value);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Which updates the contents of the following form based on a JSON query:

```
<label for="eventLocation">Event Location:</label><select name="eventLocation" id="eventLocation">
<option value="5">Buckstone</option>
<option value="18">Sandiways: Begg</option>
<option value="16">Wing Drumble Wood</option>
<option value="17" selected></option>
<option value="19" selected></option>
<option value="20">Pwll Du</option>
<option value="21" selected></option>
<option value="22">Kinver Edge</option>
<option value="23">Sandiways: Lakeview</option>
<option value="24">Gladstone</option>
<option value="25">Cannock Chase</option>
<option value="26" selected></option>
<option value="27">Consall Scout camp</option>
<option value="28">Broadwater</option>
<option value="29">Horley</option>
<option value="30">Blackwell Court</option>
<option value="31">Roddlesworth, Lancs</option>
<option value="32">Root 'n' Branch </option>
</select></p>
<form method="post" action="/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events.php?task=commitLocationEdit">
<p><label for="name">Location Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="wideText"></p>
<p><label for="address">Location Address:</label><textarea name="address" id="address" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea></p>
<p><label for="postcode">Location postcode:</label><input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode"></p>
<p><label for="directions">Directions to Location:</label><textarea name="directions" id="directions" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></p>
<p><label for="locationType">Location Type:</label><select name="locationType" id="locationType"><option value="YHA">YHA</option>
<option value="Hostel">Hostel</option><option value="Campsite">Campsite</option>
<option value="Scout Camp (Building)">Scout Camp (Building)</option><option value="Scout Camp (Camping)">Scout Camp (Camping)</option>
<option value="8 Hour">8 Hour</option><option value="Other">Other</option>
</select></p>
<p><label for="googleMapLink">Google Map Link:</label><textarea name="googleMapLink" rows="6" cols="50" title="To get a Google Maps Link, go to www.maps.google.co.uk, find the location, and then click on the tiny gear icon in the bottom right of the screen. Click 'Share and Embed Map', choose the 'Embed Map' tab, select 'Small Map' and then copy and paste the code into this box"></textarea></p>
<p><label for="notes">Notes:</label><textarea name="notes" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></p>
<button type="submit" class="eventBookButton">Edit Location</button>
<a href="/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events.php"><input type="button" class="eventBookButton" value="Cancel" /></a>
</form>
```

What I need is to be able to update the "selected" option in the second SELECT field ("#locationType") based on the JSON data, so I need JQuery to peruse the SELECT #locationType, find the option that matches the JSON data e.g.

```
{"field":"","Type":"Hostel"}
```

and then set the option to "selected". I've found loads of ways of populating the SELECT with JSON data, but can't seem to work out how to set an option to selected with JSON data...

Can anybody help? I'm still wrapping my brain round JQuery, so please speak slowly and use short words... :)

Thanks!

Comment: quick question: Is your `eventLocation` a `multiple` select? Because if it isn't it might mess up your html seeing as multiple options have a `selected` attribute

Comment: It's not supposed to be a multiple select, but it's populated from a MySQL query and there's a couple of blank records in there which I need to tidy up... It's a work in progress which I need to fix by deleting the blank records! Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set value for `locationType` select box using below code or you can set `selected` attribute for matching option:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip();
    $("#eventLocation").on("change", function (e) {
        $.getJSON("/common/ajaxCalls.php?task=locationEdit&eventLocation=" + $("#eventLocation").val(),

        function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                if (item.field == "name") {
                    $("#name").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "address") {
                    $("#address").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "postcode") {
                    $("#postcode").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "directions") {
                    $("#directions").val(item.value);
                }
                else if (item.field == "Type") {
                    // set location type
                    $("#locationType").val(item.value);
                    // OR set 'selected' attribute using below code
                    //$("#locationType option[value="+item.value+"]").attr('selected',true); 
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! That was so simple! I'd been looking for something which would use "select option:selected" or something! One day I might learn to try the simplest option first! Thankyou! :)